# Multiple IP address problem on debian/beagleboneblack

Tags: linux, debian, ip, beagleboneblack, dhcp

I'm working on a beaglebone black with a debian system and i want change my ip by modifying "/etc/network/interfaces", this is working but when I switch from DHCP method to static method my address, (atribuate by DHCP), is not "killed" so I end up with two IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, i just use `ip addr flush eth0` after modified "/etc/network/interfaces" and before `ifdown eth0` `ifup eth0`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop and disable the DHCP client daemon.

How exactly this is done depends on which version of Debian you're using.

On older versions, which I suspect you're on, there is a `dhcpcd` service. Stop it with `systemctl stop dhcpcd` and disable it with `systemctl disable dhcpcd`.

Newer versions or alternate configurations with NetworkManager or systemd-networkd will need those services reconfigured.